# Can I use sentry to track errors originating from a specific package?

Tags: python, performance, error-handling, sentry

I am using sentry to track error and performance of my pypi package. The problem is that a lot of times it captures errors that are not at all related to my package but because my package is imported, those errors are tracked. Sometimes the same type of errors flood the dashboard.
I couldn't find anything related to this on the docs or on searching. So, what is the standard way to perform error tracking using sentry?

There is an option to filter these errors using hints through the sdk itselfy.
Then there's an option to ignore similar errors in the dashboard but that requires business plan.
Are these the only way?

I tried filtering the errors at the origin itself but then that is very hacky as you have to keep updating it with the new error msgs that you find and the process just continues forever.